# Add space in-between Capital Letters but ignore 3-letter words

Tags: python, string, python-re

I'm stuck in finding a way to add space between capital letters while ignoring the Up to 3 letter Capital words such as "CIA" or "FBI".

For example:

```
import re

elem = "Optional extrasSafes in guestrooms can be used for EUR 2.5 per nightBabysitting/childcare is available for an extra charge"
elem = re.sub(r"(\w)([A-Z])", r"\1 \2", elem)

print(elem)
elem = "Optional extras Safes in guestrooms can be used for E UR 2.5 per night Babysitting/childcare is available for an extra charge"
```

Here, the problem is that "EUR" has been converted to "E UR".

Would you know how to counter this?

Comment: `r"([a-z])([A-Z])"`

Comment: Is it not possible to simply say put in space between any lower case letter which is followed by an uppercase letter? `r"([a-z])([A-Z])", r"\1 \2"`

Comment: If you have any other edge cases beyond what the above two comments identify, you should add more sample data to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you only want to add a space at a boundary between a *lowercase* followed by an *upppercase* letter.  If so, then you may try:

```py
elem = "Optional extrasSafes in guestrooms can be used for EUR 2.5 per nightBabysitting/childcare is available for an extra charge"
output = re.sub(r'([a-z])([A-Z])', r'\1 \2', elem)
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
Optional extras Safes in guestrooms can be used for EUR 2.5 per night Babysitting/childcare is available for an extra charge
```